# Angular ui-router sub state does not update view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is a angular-ui-route configuration. My problem is about the last one, the show action of *facility*.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: helper.basepath('app.html'),
        controller: 'AppController',
        resolve: helper.resolveFor('fastclick', 'modernizr', 'icons', 'screenfull', 'animo', 'sparklines', 'slimscroll', 'classyloader', 'toaster', 'whirl')
    })
    .state('app.facility', {
        parent: 'app',
        url: '/facility',
        title: 'Einrichtungen',
        templateUrl: helper.basepath('Facility/Index.html'),
        controller: 'FacilityController',
        resolve: {
            Facilities: ['Facility', function(Facility) {
                return Facility.query().$promise;
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('app.facility.show', {
        url: '/:id',
        title: 'Einrichtung Detail',
        templateUrl: helper.basepath('Facility/Show.html'),
        controller: 'FacilityItemController',
        resolve: {
            Facility: ['Facility', '$stateParams', function(Facility, $stateParams) {
                return Facility.get({id: $stateParams.id}).$promise;
            }]
        }
    })
```

When I call a link like this

```
<a ui-sref=".show({id: facility.id})">{{facility.name}}</a>
```

the URL changes and the resource and the Show.html template are loaded by ajax, but the view does not change. No errors occured.

When I rename the state to app.facilityShow (no child state) the view loads. Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it. I've renamed the state `app.facility` to `app.facility.index` and defined a new state app.facility which is abstract and looks like this:

```
    .state('app.facility', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/facility',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
    })
```

The template part is necessary. Without it, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

From ui-router wiki

> A note on relative ui-sref targets:
>
> You can also use relative state paths within ui-sref, just like the relative paths passed to state.go(). You just need to be aware that the **path is relative to the state that the link lives in**, in other words the state that loaded the template containing the link.

You need to be in `app.facility` state for following `ui-sref` to work

```
<a ui-sref=".show({id: facility.id})">{{facility.name}}</a>
```

Comment: I am. And also using the absolute state has the same effect. And calling the route directly in URL causes a blank page.

Comment: any chance you can post a working jsfiddle or plnkr? or app.html and Index.html?